# Dynamically loop through and set PHP class variables

Tags: php, reflection

I have a class with several variables like:

```
class ABC
{
  $var1=0;
  $var2=0;
  ...
}
```

Instead of setting variables one by one like;

```
$ABC=new ABC();
$ABC->var1=1;
$ABC->var2=1;
...
```

How to loop through all class' (instance) variables and dynamically set them all to some value.

Comment: Now I know (as simple as that) foreach($ABC as $var=>$val)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use get_object_vars to get the non static properties of the object, and then loop through that.

```
$object_vars = get_object_vars($ABC);

foreach ($object_vars as $name => $value) {
    $ABC->{$name} = $newVal;
}
```

See more information here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: and within the loop, you can set their value like this: $ABC->{$name} = $newVal;

Comment: What about if im inside a static class function and I want to use it with the class properties?